# How to create columns in JDL, that only accepts two values, Y or N? Y meaning Yes and N meaning No

Tags: java, spring, database, jhipster, jdl

```
entity Platform {
    platformName String required maxlength(100),
    onPermiseFlag String maxlength(1),
    cloudFlag String maxlength(1) 
}
```

The column `'onPermiseFlag'` and `'cloudFlag'` can have only two value either `'Y'` or `'N'`?
How to add validation for this?

How to add validations in JDL so that these two columns take only two values either 'Y' or 'N'

Comment: entity Platform {
 platformName String required maxlength(100),
    onPermiseFlag String maxlength(1) pattern(/^[NY]+\d$/),
    cloudFlag String maxlength(1) pattern(/^[NY]+\d$/)
}

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it using regexp, add the following:

```
onPermiseFlag(pattern("^[NY]$")),
cloudFlag(pattern("^[NY]$"))
```

EDIT 1:

```
entity Platform {
    platformName String required maxlength(100),
    onPermiseFlag String maxlength(1) {
        validate {
            if (onPermiseFlag != "N" && onPermiseFlag != "Y") {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("WHATEVER YOU WANT")
            }
        }
    },
    cloudFlag String maxlength(1) {
        validate {
            if (cloudFlag != "N" && cloudFlag != "Y") {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("WHATEVER YOU WANT")
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Not working...there is some error in the statement.

Comment: MismatchedTokenException: Expecting token of type --> REGEX <-- but found --> '"^[NY]$"' <-- at line: 24, column: 43

Comment: Its not recognizing it as a Token, try quitting the " around it

Comment: still an error...

Comment: Should I remove the maxlength validation too?

Comment: entity Platform {
 platformName String required maxlength(100),
    onPermiseFlag String maxlength(1) pattern(/^[NY]+\d$/),
    cloudFlag String maxlength(1) pattern(/^[NY]+\d$/)
}

Comment: still not working..

Comment: updated answer without regexp solution

Comment: now this is the error

Comment: unexpected character: ->!<- at offset: 669, skipped 1 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a boolean in entity and a String in DTO? This is usually a good practice to decouple presentation from storage design.

Anyway, if you want to use String, you could use enums.

https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/enums

```
enum OnPremise { Y, N}

enum Cloud { Y, N}

entity Platform {
    platformName String required maxlength(100),
    onPermiseFlag OnPremise,
    cloudFlag Cloud
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a single enum, this way you could make it evolve if in future you need to add another kind of deployment.

```
enum Deployment{ ON_PREMISE, CLOUD}

entity Platform {
    platformName String required maxlength(100),
    deployment Deployment
}
```